# Issue with Scikit learn converting categorical to numeric varaibles

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, scikits

I have the following code, where I'm converting categorical variables into numeric ones.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
var_mod = ['Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed','Property_Area','Loan_Status']
le = LabelEncoder()
for i in var_mod:
    df[i] = le.fit_transform(df[i])
print(df.dtypes)
```

I'm getting an error as

```
'>'  is not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

Please advise, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incorrect - misread your question.

Comment: is working the code. check indentation.

Comment: It is getting complied so , indentation is not a issue

Comment: You should post the full stack trace of error. This error doesnt seem to be related specifically to scikit-learn, but more of a python error